# Escaping Question Mark (?) in SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: sql

In the various SQL products I use, a question mark (?) marks an input parameter in a query.

How do I escape that behavior and search for text that contains a question mark, for example...

```
SELECT *
FROM   A_TABLE
WHERE  A_FIELD = 'This is a question mark not an input parameter?'
```

...where the question mark above is a literal question mark, not a place holder.  If the answer is product specific, I am currently using Derby (aka Java DB).

Comment: I don't think the query you show needs any kind of escaping. There is no special meaning to a ? inside of a string. But if you use JDBC, you should use bind variables (which take care of the things that do need to be escaped, such as quotes).

Comment: Or did you mean to ask about LIKE queries?

Comment: The query in question is with an equal sign `where a_afield = 'text?text'`.  I am using JDBC.  I cannot get it to match when there is a question mark in the text.  So I should be looking at bind variables?

Comment: I think you should look at parameterizing your queries.

Comment: Are you sure your data also has a question mark? Not something unprintable that will display as a question mark?

Comment: @Thilo: That is a possibility I will investigate.  So what I am getting is that I do not need to escape a question mark, I should look and bind variables and/or parameterizing my query.

Comment: @Adnan:  "Behaviour" is an accepted spelling for that word, and the one used in the UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape `?` at all. It has no special meanings with the `WHERE` clause as in the case you posted.

Comment: Except I too am experiencing the problem of having the ASP classic runtime interpret any single question mark as a parameter insertion point, then throwing an error (eg: column "[Funded?]" doesnt work)

Comment: Postgres uses a literal ? as a jsonb operator, so my area of interest is generating a query such as `SELECT * from my_table where my_jsonb_column ? 'my_key'`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned previously, a '?' following an equals will not act as a wildcard. To search for any rows within a field that contain a question mark, use:

```
SELECT * FROM A_TABLE
WHERE A_FIELD LIKE '%[?]%'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is to check if the `jsonb` column has the key you specified then simply adding `?` will return `Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter`.

In mybatis the solution is instead of using single question mark (`?`) you have to use double question mark (`??`).

For example:
`SELECT * from table where jsonb_column ?? 'key'`