# PostgreSQL json select query replacement in PHP Yii2

Tags: php, json, postgresql, yii2, postgresql-9.4

Is there any replacement for this query in PHP Yii2?

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column ?& array['2', '1', '3', '4'];`

**my_column = jsonb**

Because i get this error

```
Error Info: Array
(
  [0] => 42601
  [1] => 7
  [2] => ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
  LINE 1: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column $1& array['2', '1', '3',       '...
                                                 ^
)
```

I'm using **PHP Yii2 and PostgreSQL 9.4**:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column ?& array['2', '1', '3', '4'];";`

`$model = TestModel::findBySql($sql)->asArray()->all();`

The purpose of this query is compare if the value exists in the database.

The database have:

1. `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`
2. `["1", "2", "3"]`

And it works in the pgAdmin3 SQL Editor.

[PostgreSQL 9.41 jsonb Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

Comment: PostgreSQL likes to use numbered placeholders (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, ...) so something in PHP is converting the `?` in `?&` to `$1` as though the `?` was a placeholder. That's where the odd `$1` is coming from. Don't know enough about the PHP interface to tell you how to fix it though, sorry.

Comment: First thought was to wrap `$sq`l in `yii\db\Expression` but seems like it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, `?` is alias for `jsonb_exists()` function. `?&` is alias for `jsonb_exists_all()`. So, you can write you query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE jsonb_exists_all('my_column', array['2', '1', '3', '4']);
```

Comment: `PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException`

`pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near jsonb_exists_all`

Comment: I tried this:

`TestModel::find()
          ->where("jsonb_exists_all(my_column, array['2', '1', '3', '4'])")
          ->asArray()
          ->all();`

As i needed for Yii2 and it worked! It solved my problem, you are amazing! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the SQL String is possibly what's missing. So something like this should ideally work:

```
SELECT * FROM service WHERE test2 \?& array['2', '1', '3', '4'];
```

Comment: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"` and it generated `\$1&`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490170/php-pdo-escape-question-mark-so-it-doesnt-think-it-is-a-placeholder and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175365/escaping-question-mark-in-sql-where-clause. Seems like it's not required.

Comment: The "?" is required for PostgreSQL to compare in the `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

As a quick temporary solution, I used the `pg_query`

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "test";
$pass = "test";
$db = "test";

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
          or die("Could not connect to server\n");

//my_column type is jsonb
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column ?& array['2', '1', '3']";

$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");

$data = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);

pg_close($con);
```

But I couldn't find a way to make it work with `Yii2`. hope this help others.